# Notice: Undefined index: ag in E:\wamp\www\upload files\nestedif.php on line 3

Tags: php

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="fm" action="C:\wamp\www\control\nestedif.php" method="post">
<h1 align=center>
Age<input type="text" name="ag"><br>
gender<input type="radio" name="gn" value="M">M
<input type=radio name=gn value="F">F<br>
<input type=submit name=submit value=submit>
<input type=reset name=reset value=reset>
</h1>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<h1 align=center>
<?php
$age=$_POST ['ag'];
$gen=$_POST['gn'];
if($age>=18)
{
    if($gen=="M")
    {
        echo "you are allowed to party";
    }
    else
    { 
        echo "you are not male,so that not allowed to party";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "you are not major, so that not allowed to party";
}
?>
</h1>
```

> Notice: Undefined index: ag in
>   E:\wamp\www\upload files\nestedif.php
>   on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: gn in
>   E:\wamp\www\upload files\nestedif.php
>   on line

Answer (score 0):

The `'ag'` and `'gn'` keys do not exist in the `$_POST` array, use [`isset`](http://us.php.net/isset) to check if they do:

```
if(!isset($_POST['ag']) || !isset($_POST['gn'])) {
   //throw error here...
}
```